# Why is this simple code causing my app to freeze?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My app kept freezing with no reason so I simplified the code until I contained the problem.
Apparently having two synclock (one in a simple sub and another in a timer) caused it. This is the simplified code:

```
    String var1 = "";
    String var2 = "";
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(test_sub);
        thread.Start();
    }
    private void test_sub()
    {
        lock (var1)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000000);
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (var2){}
    }
```

Timer 1 is enabled by default with 1s delay between ticks. As soon as button1 is press, the UI freezes. Can anyone please explain what's causing this weird behavior and what can be done about it? Thanks!

Comment: You're sleeping the UI thread with the `Thread.Sleep(1000000)`. Once that happens the UI is going to lock up for `1000` seconds.

Comment: @R.J.Dunnill - The OP hasn't shown us the timer code. `test_sub` seems to be independent of the timer.

Comment: @Enigmativity The sleep function is used inside the test_sub method, which is called by a new thread, not the main one. So the UI shouldn't freeze. Also, thats the timer code (its just a lock for var2)

Comment: If an answer solves your problem mark it as an acceptable answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark A. Chiesa‘s reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is not in the Thread, or in the lock per se.
The problem is in the objects used to lock: the two locks are locking on the empty string, which is optimized to use the `String.Empty` instance.

So your code reads:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(test_sub);
    thread.Start();
}
private void test_sub()
{
    lock (String.Empty)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000000);
    }
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock (String.Empty){}
}
```

Which is going to lock the UI thread as soon as timer1_Tick is entered, because the timer (running on the UI thread) is going to lock the same object instance as the `test_sub` (running on a separate thread).

To ensure two locks are used, you should declare your lock objects like this:

```cs
private readonly object _lock1 = new object();
private readonly object _lock2 = new object();
```

This guarantees no external locking happens on the same objects, and that the two lock objects are distinct instances.

Comment: The OP's code will still lock up the UI with your suggested change. You're half way to the right answer.

Comment: What do you mean? The OP code deadlocks. If it could be changed to lock over _lock1 in one method and _lock2 on the other, it would work.

Comment: No, the OP is calling `Thread.Sleep(1000000)` and that'll lock up the UI regardless of the rest of the code.

Comment: In fact, because of the `Sleep` the timer doesn't even get a chance to run so it never hits the `lock` anyway.

Comment: No. it will not. It is run in a separate thread, so it will definitely not lock the UI thread per se. It does because the lock object is shared, because var1 and var2 are unintentionally the same instance.

Comment: IMHO, you're not understanding the root cause.

Comment: Even if the timer does run in a different thread it has to push the execution of the timer event onto the UI thread and if that's blocked by the `Sleep` the timer code does not execute.

Comment: "IMHO, you're not understanding the root cause." - Ditto.

Comment: @Enigmativity: you don't even know what kind of timer is used, so that's a bold assumption.

Comment: @DavidLibido - It doesn't matter what timer is used. The UI thread is sleeping and the OP is asking why the UI is freezing. The timer and the locks are not the cause of the problem. The big fat sleep is the issue.

Comment: It does. A system.windows.forms.timer runs on the UI thread, a system.threading.timer runs on a separate thread.

Comment: @A.Chiesa - Sorry, my mistake. I misread the `Thread` code. I apologise.

Comment: @A.Chiesa - You'll need to edit the answer for me to remove the down-vote.

Comment: @Enigmativity I would edit, if I could understand what should be changed. What do you think is missing? It's a real question, not a rethoric one. And sorry if I was confrontational. I felt picked on.

Comment: @A.Chiesa you're 100% right! I just changed the value of the two variables (var1="A", var2="B") and it worked! Spent a lot of time trying to understand thing and now its clear. Thanks!

Comment: @Flabian make yourself a favor and **do not lock on strings**. They are cached and shared. Use the pattern in my answer: lock on private objects.

Comment: Btw, if the answer is correct, you can accept it.

Comment: @A.Chiesa - If you can make a minor change then I can change my vote. Right now I'm locked out (pardon the pun) from doing that.

Comment: @Enigmavity oh, now I got it! Edited